# How to completely reset/erase the keyring?

Tags: keyrings

Something happened to my keyring, I think chrome asked for a new password to create a new keyring and erased the old one, but now the process repeats. I save a few passwords and then it resets it again.

How do I completely swipe/remove/erase the keyring, so that this problem stops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open `~/.gnome2/keyrings/`, remove all the files there that end with `.keyring`.

Next time keyring shows up for any reason do not enter a password for it and verify that you want to use unsafe storage. Keyring will still save your passwords and will not ask you again for a password.

Another option is to disable keyring so the deamon does not run but then you wont have keyring saving your passwords for you common programs.

Answer (score 15):

On Ubuntu 13.10 or later:

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings -fr
```

Next time, when setup your keyring question appears just don't setup any.

Answer (score -2):

A way I liked is the old way and it worked:

Press <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+T</kbd>.

Then, the terminal opens up, and then in there enter:

```
passwd


joeri@joeri-NC10:~$ passwd
Nieuw UNIX-wachtwoord invoeren: 
Nieuw UNIX-wachtwoord herhalen: 
passwd: wachtwoord is met succes aangepast
joeri@joeri-NC10:~$ sudo emacs
[sudo] password for joeri: 
joeri@joeri-NC10:~$ ^C
joeri@joeri-NC10:~$
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the keyring? First you change the user password, which is totally separate from the keyring, and then you open `emacs` (but with no particular document) as `root`...and you do it in a way that is [highly inadvisable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo). This would make a little bit of sense if configuration files needed to be *edited*, but they don't--to reset the keyring, they need to be *removed*.

Comment: Whoa, harsh. Clearly just a misunderstanding on their part.