# Disabling Password and Key Login

Tags: gnome, 12.10, password

I want to disable the login prompt to access the Passwords and Keys. Right clicking the prompt does not bring up a change password dialogue. Under Applications > System Tools >Preferences there is "Passwords and Keys" but right clicking that does not allow me to change the password either. There is no Password and Keys selection under Accessories. I used to be able to change the password to a blank character, which allowed it to automatically login, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that now.

Using Gnome 3 in 12.10
Thank you

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78344/how-to-completely-reset-erase-the-keyring will help you disable the keyring

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I got confused by Automatic login mentioned in the question. For reset the keyring setting, delete all the files with `.keyring` exntention from `~/.gnome2/keyrings/` location. Open Pasword and keys setting, create a new `Password Keyring` entry with name `login` and enter the same password as your login account. Then it will accept your login password as keyring password and you won't get the keyring password prompts.

Comment: Not what is being asked

Comment: I do not have a /keyrings/ directory under .gnome2.